# Email address of Logged-in User using JS Link

Tags: jslink, client-side-rendering, ctx

I am using Client Side Rendering with JSLink in SharePoint 2013. How to get the email address of Logged in User using JS Link? I was trying to use Ctx.CurrentUser.Email which returns undefined.

Comment: You need to load the current user before using it

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
    var currentUser;
    function init(){
        this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
        currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
        this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
        this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        //currentUser.get_email()
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```